# How to : bind ngModel to a property's value in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular4-forms

I want to ngModel to a property's value like below

//below code is just to explain what I want to achieve

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<input [ngModel]="question.model" />'
})
export class Test{
     @Input() bind : {to : {me : 'hello' }}
     question = {model : 'bind.to.me'}
}
```

the resultant template should be like

```
<input [ngModel]="bind.to.me" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Input() bind : {to : {me : 'hello' }};
```

should be

```
@Input() bind = {to : {me : 'hello' }};
```

otherwise you just specify that the type of the property is `{to : {me : 'hello' }}` instead of the value.

Comment: bind is an input so that will ideally come from parent component, consider bind just as a placeholder for an input from parent

Comment: I don't think this is possible. `[ngModel]="bind[question.model[first]][question.model[second]]"` with `{model : {first : 'to'}, { second: 'me'}}` should work. You need to know the depth in advance, or you use a helper method that uses `let props = bind.to.me.split('.');` and then iterates over `bind` to get the value, assigns the value to a field and then `ngModel` binds to that field.